# how to post these data in json format in android

Tags: android, json

{
  "Message": "Categories Details",
  "CategoriesDetails": [
    {
      "catid": 1,
      "catname": "AboutUs",
      "apiid": 1,
      "apiurl": "http://some url",
      "method": "POST",
      "json_datatype": "JSON"
    }
  ]
}

Comment: As usual with some http client library. This topic is well covered so the question is what had you tried already?

Comment: http://square.github.io/retrofit/ - i recommend this.

Comment: Don't know how to send ??

Comment: Use retrofit/volley library to post this data

Answer (score 0):

Check this.i think to help you. http://hmkcode.com/android-send-json-data-to-server/

Comment: it should be posted as comment, some time links stop working.

Answer (score 0):

Create a [JSONObject](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html) and put all the data you want in it. Here's an example :

```
    JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
    try{
        data.put("key2", "value3");
        data.put("key2", "value2");
        //similarly put all the values here
        // you can add JSONObject or JSONArray also as the value
    }catch (JSONException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Then you can use some networking library like [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html), [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) or [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) to send it to the server.

You can read more about each of them on the web. There're enough working examples available for you to learn!

Here's a sample request in Volley :

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(methodType,mUrl,params,getResponseListener(),getErrorListener()){
                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                    //set request headers.
                    return setRequestHeaders();
                }
                @Override
                protected Response<JSONObject> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "cookie : " + response.headers.get("Set-Cookie"));
                    saveResponseCookie(response); //get response headers.
                    return super.parseNetworkResponse(response);
                }
            };
            jsonRequest.setTag(requestTag);
            jsonRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                    20000,
                    DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                    DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
            requestQueue.add(jsonRequest);
```

Read more about `JsonObjectRequest` in volley [here](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request.html).

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest going with [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/). It is a library maintained by Square, super easy to use (see a short tutorial in the link), and reduces boilerplate code to a minimum.